# Differentiability of the square root function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $g $ and  $f $ be two real functions (both defined on an interval or a union of intervals (closed intervals mainly)), such that: $f(x)=\sqrt{g(x)} $ and $g(x)$ is either a polynomial or a rational function, then:

1. Are there any specific conditions so that we guarantee that $f$ is differentiable on it's domain or not?
2. If we easily calculated the derivative function, can we say that the domain of the derivative is the same domain where $f $ is differentiable?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $f$ is certainly diff'able where $g$ is positive (use the chain rule). Additionally, the one-sided derivative *may* exist at roots of $g$. I understand that whenever a root of $g$ is an interior point of $f$ (so a root of even multiplicity), you want diff'ability? This is the case if the multiplicity of each such root is $>2$.

Comment: Thank you, of course there is no problem when g is positive. And the big question is: is there any general conditions for g when we want to study the differentiablity of f on some point a which is a root of g